# FileInterceptor wouldn't read .env variables

Tags: nestjs, multer, google-cloud-storage, openshift-env-variables

Using nestjs and its library `@UseInterceptors` to save a file to GCS.
I cannot call variables from `process.env.VARIABLE` using `multerGoogleStorage` library.

So here's my code

```
@UseInterceptors(
FileInterceptor('file', {
  storage: multerGoogleStorage.storageEngine({
    bucket: 'maca_files',
    projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    bucket: process.env.GCS_BUCKET,
    keyFilename: process.env.KEYFILENAME,
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, `/${file.originalname}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  async saveFile(
  @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  @Req() req: Request,
) {
   return file.path;
}
```

This is my Controller file, and I have imoprted

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
```

before I imported

```
import * as multerGoogleStorage from 'multer-google-storage';
```

The code has no problem since it perfectly works when I replace those env. variables with the real variables or paths.

I think the problem is that GCS is called before the file compiles the whole env files. I mostly get undefined problem.

So my question is

1. what is causing the problems?
2. How would I call env. variables before GCS?

I have tried so many methods to make this work but none of them did. I need a legit solution